# impact of interest rate and benefits for IMF

Tags: interest-rate, imf

We know that when interest rates are high, the economy slows and inflation decreases. when interest rates are low, the economy grows, and inflation increases. Now govt wants low inflation as it has to take votes from poor people. IMF wants govt to increase inflation as it wants it money back that it borrowed to govt of Pakistan.

The flip side is that IMF wants govt to increase interest rates, what is the benefit of increased interest rates for IMF? It's complicated.

Comment: what does "economy slows" mean. Do you mean [economy's growth](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sluggisheconomy.asp#:~:text=A%20sluggish%20economy%20is%20a,slow%2C%20flat%2C%20or%20declining.&text=Extended%20periods%20of%20sluggishness%20can,of%20a%20potentially%20steeper%20downturn.) is slows?